# Is there any way to use typescript generic class instance or methods?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rest, generics

Specifically, I'm trying to improve deserialization in my Angular project. I have a base HTTP class that abstracts away some of the universal aspects of interacting with my REST service:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

export class BaseHttpService {

...

  protected get<T>(url: string, params: object = {}, options: object = {}): Observable<any> {
    
    // some operations every get request needs to do 

    return this.httpClient.get<T>(url, { params: httpParams, ...options });
  }

...
```

And I'm using the `cerialize` library to handle object deserialization, specifically for Java Date (millisecond since epoch format) conversion to Javascript Date, and occasionally some helper methods that I want stored on the class (as opposed to just taking the JSON in through a Typescript interface). So my use of this method always looks something like:

```
import { Deserialize } from 'cerialize';
import { ModelA } from './models';

export class SomeControllerService {
...
    constructor(private baseHttpService: BaseHttpService) {}

    someMethod<ModelA>(): Observable<ModelA> {
        return this.get<ModelA>().pipe(map(response => Deserialize(response, ModelA)));
    }
...
```

What I want to do is remove the need for `.pipe(map(...` which ends up being in every single method that returns a REST response object and is basically the same, just with a different model depending on the endpoint. In Java, I believe you could use the generic in the base service as an input to the Deserialize function like `(response => Deserialize(response, T.class))`. I also want to avoid adding another parameter to the base `get` function. Per my title, I could also see a solution that refactors to calling a function on the generic, that the individual models could implement specific deserialization logic in, but again, since the generic is just a type, that doesn't seem possible. Am I just running up to a limitation of Typescript?

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime but class constructors do, so you should be able to pass those around anywhere you're thinking you need to pass a type.  But without a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mpgdbN) it's hard to provide specific advice. Could you flesh the code here out into a self-contained example?

Comment: Have you tried paying with the options passed to the `HttpClient#get` method? See https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get, in particular the parameters `observe` and `responseType`. When set to `{observe: 'body', responseType: 'json'}` you don't need the deserialization.